# Android - Kotlin Coroutines for handling IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, illegalstateexception

In my Android App, I use `Room` as local database to store the Account information of a user. When I make a simple `Room` request to retrieve the `Account` object stored in the database, I get the following error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Here, is the `Fragment` code from which I make the local database request:

```
// AccountInformationFragment.kt


accountDataFragmentViewModel.retrieveAccountData(accountId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
       // do some stuff
    })
```

In the `ViewModel` class I have implemented `retrieveAccountData()` like this:

```
    // AccountInformationFragmentViewModel.kt        

    // used to get the account from the local datasource
    fun retrieveAccountData(id:Long): LiveData<Account>{
        val result = MutableLiveData<Account>()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val account = authRepository.retrieveAccountData(id)
            result.postValue(account) 
        }
        return result
    }
```

In the `Repository` class, I have implemented `retrieveAccountData()` like this:

```
// AccountRepository.kt

suspend fun retrieveAccountData(accId:Long): Account =
        accountDao.retrieveAccountData(accId)
```

I understand that I have to use some sort of asnyc operation because the local database operation may take a long time when its performed on the main thread.
But in the `ViewModel` class I launched the coroutine inside the `viewModelScope`. Is that not enough? Based on the exception, it seems not. So, is there someone who could tell me how to do this correctly.

EDIT:

Here is the Dao class :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM account_table WHERE id = :id")
fun retrieveAccountData(id: Long) : Account
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your `retrieveAccountData` a suspending method? If not, why not? That's what automatically jumps the database access to a background thread.

Comment: I have added the retrieveAccountData() from AccountDao class. Do you mean that I have just need to add the suspend keyword ?

Comment: @abdullahcelik yes, try adding `suspend` to methods in `repository` and `dao` that you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines), if you want Room to automatically move to a background thread to run your `@Query`, you can make your method a `suspend` method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM account_table WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun retrieveAccountData(id: Long) : Account
```

Comment: Thank you. Basically, I just forgot the suspend keyword. Now, I understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

RoomDB supports LiveData. You could return the query result as a livedata which is by default does the operation in the background thread and observe it in your UI layer. I have modified your query below which will return LiveData instead of Account.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM account_table WHERE id = :id")
fun retrieveAccountData(id: Long) : LiveData<Account>
```